# What causes ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute) on shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, select-by-attribute, error-000358

My script runs perfectly for feature classes, but not shapefiles. It crashes at the point of selection, provided there is a query.

```
gp.Workspace = "C:/someworkspace"
fc = "featureclass.shp"
query = "[SOME_TEXT_FIELD] = \"666\""
gp.MakeFeatureLayer(fc, "flyr")
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("flyr", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

returns

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute
>   (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Tested a similar simple example in the Python Shell. This runs fine with a geodatabase and feature class. I assume there is some sort of special treatment for shapefiles I'm not aware of, but arcgis desktop help does not specify anything.

Comment: Try using single-quotes around the target value in your SQL query: `query = "[SOME_TEXT_FIELD] = '666'"`

Comment: Did try that, both with and without escape characters. I don't think the query should behave any differently. I thought maybe I could create the feature layer without the file extension, but that doesn't work. My ArcMap has been behaving a little strangely (and slowly) at times since the connection for my ArcInfo license on the server has been a bit intermittent today, so I wondered if that that had anything to do with it.

Comment: Ok, have you tried using quotation marks instead of brackets around the field? `query = "\"SOME_TEXT_FIELD\" = '666'"`

Comment: More specific than that -- it works with query = "\"FIELD\" = \'121\'". I'll need an if statement for this I suppose. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This, and only this, works - `query = "\"FIELD\" = \'121\'"`. Let it be known that gp is much picker with shapefiles than feature classes when it comes to SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not like using the escape character '' then this should work too:

```
query = '"FIELD" = ' + "'121'"
```

This ArcPy [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001r000000) (that applies equally to arcgisscripting) mentions that:

> The field delimiters used in a SQL expression differ depending on the
> format of the queried data. For instance,
> file geodatabases and shapefiles use double quotes (" "), personal
> geodatabases use square brackets ([ ]), and ArcSDE geodatabases don't
> use field delimiters

---

For a number of versions now I have been preferring to use the simpler syntax below:

```
query = "FIELD = '121'"
```

Comment: Yes, though I had difficulty finding that in 9.3. help for gp. I actually do prefer the escape character since it's slightly faster to run in python than using +.