# ArcPy select by attribute fails with invalid syntax error message

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I am trying to use ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro v 2.8 to select by attribute from two different attributes in a shapefile.  My code fails with a ERROR 000358: Invalid expression.

I have used ModelBuilder to build a valid expression and exported the model to a Python script. I can confirm in my map that the query is working correctly in ModelBuilder. In the exported model-as-script the select by attribute looks like this:

```
telemetryUTM, Count = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_layer_or_view=telemetryUTM_2_, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause="TagID = 112 And Date = timestamp '2019-04-12'", invert_where_clause="")
```

My code builds a text string to use as the where_clause and that string print like this:

```
"TagID = 112 And Date = timestamp '2019-04-12'"
```

Here is the code I use that is failing with the error:

```
in_fc = r"C:\GIS\telemetrytags\projected_data\telemetryUTM.shp"
tag_ids = []
ping_dates = []
fields = ['TagID', 'Date']
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in tag_ids:
            tag_ids.append(row[0])
        if row[1] not in ping_dates:  
            ping_dates.append(row[1])
for tag in tag_ids:
    for ping in ping_dates:
        query =  '"TagID = ' + str(int(tag)) + ' And Date = timestamp ' +'\'' + str(ping).split(' ')[0] + '\'"'
        print(query)
        this_fish, ping_count = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_fc, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause=query)
```

Why is my code failing with a 000358 error?

Comment: Missing "  around Date?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80204/what-causes-executeerror-error-000358-invalid-expression-failed-to-execute-se Note that different data sources have different SQL flavors. Shapefile's parser requires quotes (`"`) around the field name. If the field is text, then apostrophes (`'`) are *always* required around the string literal.

Comment: Also, as currently formatted, you have one Boolean column name with spaces in it.

Comment: Thanks this worked:     query =  '\"TagID\" = ' + str(int(tag)) + ' And \"Date\" = timestamp ' +'\'' + str(ping).split(' ')[0] +'\''

Comment: Best practice recommends using `str.format()` (string math is a blight on code legibility and performance). `query = "\"TagID\" = '{:s}' AND \"Date\" = timestamp '{:s}'".format(str(int(tag)),str(ping).split(' ')[0])'` or better yet, `query = "{:s} = '{:s}' AND {:s} = timestamp '{:s}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(in_fc,'TagID'),str(int(tag)),arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(in_fc,'Date'),str(ping).split(' ')[0])`